# How can I add a yellow marker to my mouse pointer?

Tags: windows, mouse

I am about to teach a class with a laptop attached to a big screen.

I wish to have the mouse bigger, and with some yellow marker on it.

What (free) software is good for that (for windows) ?

Answer (score 5):

[ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) allows you to to draw things and zoom on your screen whatever program you are using.

If you choose a lower resolution while presenting, you will also get a bigger mouse.
If you can't risk a decrease in resolution, an alternative is to [set a bigger mouse scheme](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/pointerscheme.mspx).

If you are using Powerpoint slides, you can [write on the slides with a pen](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/powerpoint-help/write-on-slides-with-the-powerpoint-pen-HA001056313.aspx).

I would suggest walking to the back of the class before a lesson to see how big the mouse really is...

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel : Mouse : Pointers : Browse... and select a .cur file that you like.

I *think* these are actually .ico files and if so you should be able to edit them with Microsoft Paint.

Answer (score 1):

A **Freeware software** does indeed exist to **create custom mouse pointers**.

Its called [**Real World Cursor Editor**](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-maker) and here's the [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/realworld-cursor-editor-%E2%80%93-for-those-who-love-to-make-their-own-free-cursors/) through which I found this free utility.

The site also features [**custom cursor gallery**](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-library), you can have a look if you find something useful.

Comment: This is funny (the gallery :) )

Comment: yea I had a good laugh too it looks like windows 98 stuff, didn't go through it all but I figured you might find something useful if you searched.

Comment: Yellow cursors set: (http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-set/yellow), and Yellow circle (http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-detail/24824)